# I'm looking for a good USB-Switch with hotkey support

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors

Right, so I am essentially looking for something like [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MXXQKGM) to toggle which device my keyboard and mouse go to. But honestly I'm looking for a solution where I can toogle it also by pressing a hotkey on my keyboard or a macro.

Comment: Switch devices like these are usually "pass-through", so you can't send instructions from the peripheral device you have connected send a signal directly to the switch. Everything I've found in the last half hour that claims to have hotkey support has terrible reviews, most of them dealing with the hotkey issue. This is anecdotal from my search, but you'd likely be better off finding a KVM switch or a USB switch with the physical button on an extended cable, that way you can  route it somewhere more convenient.

Comment: @jcam3 I am using Mouse without Borders now, but it sometimes lags and additionally it has trouble with games. I will probably buy a switch with a button and code a rasberry pi to close the circuit somehow and then trigger that with a hotkey from my PC and plug it together with an USB cable to trigger it.